# Store string with multiple apostrophes next to each other

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I wanted to make a MySql database that held a relatively basic user profile. I wanted to make a description section, but I've encountered a lot of issues. I first noticed that apostrophes could cause crashes, so I looked up a way to "escape" them `str = str.replace("'", "''");` and it worked fine for a while...until someone typed multiple apostrophes next to each other in this exact same format

> '''test'''

This caused my code to inevitably crash, leaving me confused as to what could have caused this issue in the first place.

Thanks for the time
-Blazy

Comment: Why not just escape data properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx `/'+/g` to find one or more apostrophes (`'`):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('input').value.replace(/'+/g, "''"));
function formatStr(input){
  var str = input.value;
  str = str.replace(/'+/g, "''");
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="'''test'''" oninput="formatStr(this)">
```